# Code has changed in the new version of python

Tags: python

I need some help because I'm coding a pong game right now but the video that's helping me the python version is 3.6 and I'm writting it in python 3.8, and I've arrived at a problem where the error that I get is
`"turtle has no attribute dx"`, does someone know what I have to write it the new version of python?

```
while True:
    wn.update()
    
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)
```

That's the code it's to make the ball move.

Comment: You can find out available member functions and attributes by calling `print(dir(ball))`

Comment: Well it clearly says ball has no attribute 'dx' maybe u forgotten to define it inside that class. Please check it once

Answer (score 1):

I got the code from where you are saying,
http://christianthompson.com/sites/default/files/Pong/pong.py

Here, In this section of code

```
# Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("square")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = 2
```

He has defined values of dx and dy.
It is not the error of versions.